# How to run php script on Google App Engine?

Tags: php, ajax, google-app-engine

I have a problem with a php-script in the Google App Engine environment.

I try to call a php script with an ajax-call, but the success callback always returns the unprocess php file (`<?php .... ?>`)

The ajax-call look like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/contactform-process.php",
        data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&message=" + message + "&terms=" + terms, 
        success: function(text) {
            console.log('Hello')
            if (text == "success") {
                cformSuccess();
            } else {
                cformError();
                csubmitMSG(false, text);
            }
        }
    });
```

I assume that I have to declare something that the Google App Engine environment is handling the  php file correctly. My current app.yaml:

```
runtime: php74

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: static/index.html
  upload: static/index.html

- url: /de
  static_files: static/de/index.html
  upload: static/de/index.html

- url: /en
  static_files: static/en/index.html
  upload: static/de/index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*)

- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: auto

- url: /contactform-process.php
  script: auto
```

Does anybody knows whats missing, so the php file gets processed in the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first handler that `/contactform-process.php` matches is `/(.*)`, which is a static file handler so it just returns your PHP file as-is (does not execute it).

You want it to match `(.+\.php)$` *BEFORE* it matches `/(.*)` so you need to switch the order of those two in your list of handlers.